# PHP: Replace city name

Tags: php

I want to match an array against a string and replace city name contained in string with a dash (-)

For example:

```
$str = 'French Tuition In Newyork' OR $str = 'French Tuition Newyork';

$arrCity = array('Newyork', 'Washington');
```

I want to replace the above strings like below,

```
$str = 'French Tuition - Newyork' AND $str = 'French Tuition - Newyork';
```

Thus if last word is city it should be pre-appended by dash (-).
OR
If the last word is city and before last word is "IN", the "IN" should be replaced by dash (-).

Comment: so where are you stucked in getting *what you want* ???

Comment: i want to add dash (-) in front of last word in string if it is a city name, and i do not know how to achieve that.

Comment: at least give it a try and share with us what you did, we can then get you in the right direction...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply do it with this.

```
<?php
$str = 'French Tuition In Newyork';
$str2 = 'French Tuition Newyork';
$arrCity = array('Newyork', 'Washington');
$temp = array();

$split = explode(" ", $str);
$lastword = $split[count($split)-1];
$beforeLastWord = $split[count($split)-2];

if(in_array($lastword, $arrCity)) {
  if(strtolower($beforeLastWord) === 'in') {
    $split[count($split)-2] = '-';
  }
  else {
    $split[count($split)-1] = '-';
    array_push($split, $lastword);
  }
}

echo implode(" ", $split);
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, i wanted to replace city name only if it was last word in string, and you reply is perfect. An up vote for you.

Answer (score 2):

For your reference.

```
<?php

//$str = 'French Tuition Newyork';
$str = 'French Tuition In Washington'; 
$arrCity = array('Newyork', 'Washington');
$in_str = 'In';

foreach ($arrCity as $key => $value) {
  $pos = strpos($str, $value);

  if($pos) {
     $pos2 = strpos($str, $in_str);

     if($pos2) 
       $temp_str = explode($in_str, $str);
     else 
       $temp_str = explode($value, $str);

     $result = $temp_str[0] . ' - ' . $value;
     echo $result;
  }

}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$str = 'French Tuition Washington';
$arrCity = array('Newyork', 'Washington');
$cities = implode('|', $arrCity);
echo preg_replace("/(French Tuition).+({$cities})/", '$1 - $2', $str);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This's effective one ;)

```
<?php
   $str = 'French Tuition In Washington'; 
   $str1 = 'French Tuition Newyork'; 
    function dash($string)
    {
       if (strpos($string,'In') !== false) 
       {
          echo str_replace('In','-',$string);
        }
        else
        {
          $arrCity = array('Newyork', 'Washington');
          foreach($arrCity as $city)
          {
            if(strpos($string,$city))
            {
              echo str_replace($arrCity,'- '.$city,$string);
            }
          }
        }
    }

  dash($str);
  dash($str1);
?>
```

Output

```
French Tuition - Washington
French Tuition - Newyork
```